# Add behaviour to a react-router Link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have an off-canvas menu in my React app with react-router, and I'm using `<Link to="/page/name">` inside the menu.

The problem is that when the user clicks, the menu does not disappear as it would in an HTML app with page loading.

The menu gains a class when state reflects that the menu is visible - I'm wondering if there's a simple method to transition to the link **and** remove the class from the menu without re-writing the entire `<Link>` function.

Comment: Can you add an `onClick` method to the `<Link />` component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regular `<a>` tag instead with an attached `onClick` listener.

```
render() {
...
<a href="#" onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, "your/route/here"}>Click me!</a>
...
}

handleClick(myRoute, e) {
   e.preventDefault(); //prevent default <a> navigation to href (or omit the attribute)
   //remove your class here
   this.context.router.push(myRoute);
}
```

You also need to get the `router` contextType, if you haven't already:

```
static contextTypes = {
  router: React.PropTypes.object
}
```